# How to convert a set of tiles on sdcard to latitude, longitude bounding box

Tags: android, geolocation, geocoding, tile, geo

I am working on map application which can display offline maps stored on sdcard. I use OSMDroid for this purpose.
Map tiles are stored in a well known folder structure:

```
root/zoom/x/y.png
```

Where:
root - the root folder for all sublfolders
zoom - multiple subfolders of root for different zoom levels
x - multiple subfolders of zoom for x coordinate of the tile 
y - tiles with y coordinate as it's name

My current problem is that I don't know how to detect bounding box (latitude, longitude) for actual set of files, is it possible to detect it programmatically?

Comment: Are you able to determine the bounding box for one file?

Comment: unfortunately not yet

Comment: Then wouldn't it be better to rephrase your problem?

Comment: I will post an answer soon with more details